# WebSocketStompClient stompSession future timingout

Tags: spring-boot, websocket

I'm trying to connect to a Secure WebSocket service using WebSocketStompClient in a Spring Boot application, but it never get past StompSession Future get call (timing out).

I've verified this service works by using 'Smart Websocket Client' Chrome browser extension, but haven't been able to get it working with the Spring Boot client.

I'm unable to figure out what else I can do to further debug this. Not sure if this is a certificate issue or something else.

Any suggestion ?

Update: I even got this working with Java/Kotlin using 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.5.1'. It was just a one liner: connect with the same URI. I think this rules out any potential issue with the certificate.

```
val URL = "wss://service.foo/bar"
val countDownLatch = CountDownLatch(1)
val client = StandardWebSocketClient()
val stompClient = WebSocketStompClient(client)
stompClient.messageConverter = MappingJackson2MessageConverter()
val sessionHandler = MyEventSocketHandler()
val stompSessionFuture = stompClient.connect(URL, sessionHandler)

// MyEventSocketHandler::afterConnected() never got called. Doing this to figure out what is going on. 
val stompSession = stompSessionFuture.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
countDownLatch.await()
```